# Interpolation function for values from file in C, wrong return value

Tags: c

I am trying to program, using C, an interpolation function of values from a file. The thing is that the program does not give me errors when compiled but neither has it given a right value when executed. 
I have tried it in a bunch of ways but I cannot solve it. You can see my program bellow! Actually I need to program it in this way:  the interpolation function is called in a void which is used in the main! If some can help please, do not hesitate please!

the program:

```
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Standard C library headers

SOLVED PROBLEM -- THIS C CODE WORKS     *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>




#include "interpolate.h"
#include "conditions.h"




double interpolate(int ipass, char* filename, double time)
{

int i=0 ;
double prevtime=0., nexttime=0. ; 
double prevvalue=0., nextvalue=0. ; 
double readtime=0., readvalue=0. ;
double value=0. ;  
FILE *file=NULL;


file = fopen(filename,"r");


if (file != NULL)
     { 
           rewind(file) ;
           fscanf(file,"%lf %lf", &readtime , &readvalue);
           nexttime = readtime  ;
           nextvalue =  readvalue;

        while(fscanf(file,"%lf %lf", &readtime , &readvalue)==2)
      {


           /* printf("%lf %lf \n", nexttime,nextvalue);
            printf("i am in \n") ;*/
            prevtime  = nexttime  ;
            prevvalue = nextvalue ;
            nexttime  = readtime ;
            nextvalue =  readvalue;

             if(readtime>=time) 
        {   
            printf("prev values: \n") ; 
                        printf("%lf , %lf \n", prevtime, prevvalue) ;
            printf("next values: \n") ; 
                        printf("%lf , %lf \n", nexttime, nextvalue) ;
            break ;
}


           }


     } else
     {
          printf("error! could not open file \n");
          exit(-1)  ;
     }

     value = ((nextvalue-prevvalue)*(time-prevtime)/(nexttime-prevtime)) + prevvalue ;

   fclose(file);
   return value ; 


}

    void conditions()
    {        
        double q=0., var=0. ; 
        char f_q[]="test.data";

        if (f_q != '\0')
        {
            printf("choose value for time \n");
            scanf("%lf", &var) ;
            q = interpolate(1, f_q, var) ;
            printf("interpolate gives Q=%lf \n",  q);
            printf("FILENAME is:%s \n" ,f_q) ; 
        } else
         {
             printf("F_Q = \0");
         }
        return ;
    }

    int main()
    {    
        conditions();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why use a temporary array for the file-name, instead of just passing the `FILENAME` argument directly to `fopen`? Also note that traditionally all-capital words are usually used for pre-processor macros. Also, no need to use the `return` statement last in a function not returning a value, the compiler will automatically generate code to return from the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also... Please please please format your code better than that...

Comment: Have you checked `var`? Your `scanf` format is missing a specifier. You probably meant `scanf("%lf", &var)`. You probably also don't want to `exit(0)` (the whole program) when the readtime exceeds the interpolation time; just `break` the loop

Comment: You are looping through the whole file and then only calculate an interpolation for the last two lines read. Is that what you want?

Comment: `if ( READTIME>=time) exit(0);`? Do you really intend to exit the program unless `time` is greater than all the values in the file? That doesn't sound very "interpolating". Did you mean `break`?

Comment: Thanks for these answers; I actually intend to continue the loop until the value of time read in file is greater than 'time'. I then use next and previous values to do the interpolation. I have righted the missing variable specifier for “var” and used break instead of exit but still I do not have an accurate value for the interpolation.

Comment: @tafa: You don't catch the cases outside the time range in the file, but apart from hat your code seems to work now. If you still have problems, could you please give an example input with the exepcted result?

Comment: trying to 'rewind()' the file before checking if the fopen() was successful is a good way to have a seg fault event that will be very difficult to debug

Comment: 'time' is a known system function (especially if the code has a '#include <time.h>' statement)   code should not contain any 'replacements' for system functions.

Comment: good programming practice (and what is generally expected) is for #define names and const values to be all caps, separated by underscores.   I.E. #define MAX_VALUE (10).  Function names, variable names, and parameter names are generally expected to be 'camel case'  I.E. myFunctionName()

Comment: the code is closing the file, even if the file failed to open.  This does not work and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: Thank you all! This problem is solved, I am very grateful.

Comment: regarding these two lines: 'char F_Q[]="test.data";    if (F_Q != '\0')'  since the array F_Q[] is set to 'test.data', it can never by equal to '\0' so the 'if statement can/should be removed,  this 'if' statement is just cluttering the code.    on a related subject, a just opened file will have the 'file pointer' at the beginning of the file, so calling rewind() is just cluttering the code and should be removed